# System packages not exported by OSGi System Bundle

Tags: android, osgi, apache-felix

I'm new to OSGi. I am running Apache Felix on Android. I have set the system packages to be exported by the system bundle as below:

```
/** Packages exported by the system bundle. */
String SYSTEM_PACKAGES = 
    "org.osgi.framework;version=\"1.6.0\"," + 
    "org.osgi.framework.launch;version=\"1.0.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.framework.wiring;version=\"1.0.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.framework.startlevel;version=\"1.0.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle;version=\"1.0.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.framework.hooks.resolver;version=\"1.0.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.framework.hooks.service;version=\"1.1.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.framework.hooks.weaving;version=\"1.0.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.service.packageadmin;version=\"1.2.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.service.startlevel;version=\"1.1.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.service.url;version=\"1.0.0\"," +
    "org.osgi.util.tracker;version=\"1.5.0\"";

Map map = new HashMap();
map.put ( "org.osgi.framework.system.packages" , SYSTEM_PACKAGES );
// I set more properties ...
felix = new Felix ( map );
felix.start();
```

However, when I try to install the ConfigAdmin bundle, it gives a BundleException:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle 
org.apache.felix.configadmin [1]: Unable to resolve 1.0: missing requirement [1.0] 
osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.4.0)
(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

Why is it missing this requirement, when I have exported the org.osgi.framework package from the system bundle at version 1.6.0?
I have checked that the system property was correctly set, by doing:

```
// DEBUG
Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext() , 
                 felix.getBundleContext().getProperty ( "org.osgi.framework.system.packages" ) , 
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
```

Probably it is a simple mistake on my part. Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing this? Felix should automatically export those packages from the systems bundle.

And if you need to export additional packages from the system bundle, beyond those normally exported, use the [`org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra`](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Constants.html#FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA) launch configuration property.

Comment: I was doing that initially (letting Felix set the system packages for me). But since it was giving the missing requirement exception, I thought I should set it explicitly. Anyway, it turns out the error was caused by something else - I posted the reason below.

Answer (score 1):

The issue got solved. I was making a mistake while setting the extra packages parameter:

```
map.put ( "org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra" , "" );
```

Felix does not accept the empty string (I had used an empty string initially, thinking I would add package names to it later). When I removed this statement, things worked fine.

As BJ Hargrave said, no need to set the system packages.

Also, we should not pass empty strings as map values, I had not realized that.